# JQuery Mobile Footer items not displaying in 1 row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi all using JQuery to hide the overflow of list items and it's working well but the items I displaying in rows of 2 instead of all in the same row.

Anyone know why it might be doing this?

Here is the full source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>Page content goes here.</p>      
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul class="footeritems">
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="top">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="top">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="top">Three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="top">Four</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="top">Five</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="top">Six</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="top">Seven</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("ul.footeritems li:gt(3)").remove();
     $("ul.footeritems").listview('refresh');

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are referring to HTML 5. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because jquery mobile css supports footer navbar to have a maximum of five list items in a row. if there are more items it breaks it into further lines. remove any one list item and it will come in a single row

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I've added JQuery to remove the excess and it's still in multiple rows :o/

Comment: the listview refresh is not made for navbars or other bars. that is what is doing the wrong. currently there is no solution for navbars.